# Upload files from one project to another on same domain

Tags: c#, io, directory

i have 2 projects say . MyProject and MyProject.Admin

i have published these both projects to the IIS.

the tree structure is

localhost/MyProject

localhost/MyProject/Admin.

now i have to upload files to MyProject from the MyProject.Admin,

so i would like to know how to upload files from MyProject.Admin to MyProject.

while creating a directory in the MyProject i am using the path

```
if (Directory.Exists("/MyProject/Files/someFolderName"))
{
    Response.Write("Directory Already Exists");
    Response.Write("<br />"+Server.MapPath("/MyProject/Files/someFolderName"));
}
else
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory("/MyProject/Files/someFolderName");                
}
```

it says that directory already exists , but when i navigate to that location.. but i dont find any directory?

Comment: Make sure, it's not hidden.

Comment: yes it is not hidden...